# Laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough, access One->Many->One

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm pretty new to laravel. Just practicing by trying to rewrite my project management tool but i can't seem to wrap my head around the hasManyThrough relationship (if it's even the right one).

## Basis

I want every logged in *user* to have (manage) multiple *projects* and also every *customer* to have (commission) multiple *projects*.

## Current structure:

**user**
*Database*

- id
- ...

*Model*

```
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
```

**customer**
*Database*

- id
- ...

*Model*

```
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
```

**project**
*Database*

- id
- ...
- manager_id (foreign,references user.id)
- customer_id (foreign, references customer.id)

*Model*

```
    public function manager(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
```

## Goal

I want to list my Users *customers* on the Dashboard. So every **unique** *customer* that commissioned a *project*, that the *user* is managing. I don't want to assign a *customer* directly to a *user*, because every *project* should have a manager, not the *customer* itself.

## Tries

I did try to add the following to the *User* Model:

```
    public function customers(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Customer::class, Project::class);
    }
```

but i get a error, saying that there is no project_id in the *customer* table, which of course there isn't.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It may be a typo in your question but it shows the customer as using the `manager_id` in its relationship.

Comment: yes, that was from copy+pasting. I removed every foreignKey from the relationships for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since laravel can't guess that users == managers you have to define the key relationships yourself. Try this:

`return $this->hasManyThrough(Customer::class, Project::class, 'manager_id', 'id', 'id', 'customer_id');`

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through-key-conventions

Comment: This might help clarify things: https://stitcher.io/blog/laravel-has-many-through

Comment: i changed my code to use user_id instead of manager_id, but still got the error *Unknown column 'customers.project_id' in 'on clause' *.

But then using your code with user_id instead of manager_id worked, thank you!